# Python optional function argument to default to another argument's value

Tags: python, python-2.7, default-value, optional-arguments

I want to define a function with some optional arguments, let's say A (mandatory) and B (optional). When B is not given, I want it to take the same value as A. How could I do that?

I have tried this, but it doesn't work (name 'B' is not defined):

```
def foo(A, B=A):
    do_something()
```

I understand that the values of the arguments are not assigned before the body of the function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shall do this inside of your function.

Taking your original function:

```
def foo(A, B=A):
    do_something()
```

try something like:

```
def foo(A, B=None):
    if B is None:
        B = A
    do_something()
```

Important thing is, that function default values for function arguments are given at the time, the function is defined.

When you call the function with some value for `A`, it is too late as the `B` default value was already assigned and lives in function definition.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this. If `B` has a value of `None` then assign it from `A`

```
def foo(A, B=None):
    if B is None:
        B = A

    print 'A = %r' % A
    print 'B = %r' % B
```